# How to rotate particular image among multiple images drawn to canvas in android?

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I need a small help on rotating one image around its center of axis among multiple images which are drawn to canvas in android.

I am loading images to canvas like below.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mMachineBackground, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(mMachineRotator, 0, 0, null);
```

I want to rotate only the second bitmap around its center of axis instead of rotating the entire canvas(which includes first bitmap also).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can rotate around the centre axis:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

//move image

matrix.setTranslate(getXPos() - (imageWidth / 2), getYPos() - (imageHeight / 2));

//rotate image, getXPos, getYPos are x & y coords of the image

matrix.postRotate(angleInDegrees, getXPos() - imageWidth / 2, getYPos() - imageHeight / 2);

//rotatedBMP is the image you are drawing, 

canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBMP, matrix, Paint);
```

Comment: love u man...i have been searching for this for 4days finally ur answer gave me the solution. thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

```
//Drawing the Player Canon.
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           //move image
           newHeight = getHeight() - canon1[0].getHeight() - stand1.getHeight();
           Log.d(TAG, "New Height : " + newHeight);
           //matrix.setTranslate(0, getHeight() - canon1[0].getHeight() + stand1.getHeight());
           matrix.setTranslate(-newHeight,newHeight);

           //   rotate image, getXPos, getYPos are x & y coords of the image (ANgle in degree)).
           //matrix.postRotate(45, 0, getHeight() - canon1[0].getHeight() + stand1.getHeight());
           matrix.postRotate(-30,0,0);
           //Draw function. 
           canvas.drawBitmap(canon1[0], matrix, null);
```

This code which I had writen from the reference of the above code works absolutely fine.

I am able to rotate a particular image on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do this.
As far as what I have learned so far, you can rotate tho whole context, but not a single bitmap. Transformation matrix for what I know can only be applied to the whole canvas.
(I am not a canvas guru, but I am doing extensive research on your same exact question)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Can't we rotate the bitmap around its center of axis using rotate animation.
Or else. I better to go for Frame by Frame animation to get the desired rotation animation feel.
Thanks in advance.